# Restler not receiving ñ character

Tags: php, rest, character-encoding, special-characters, restler

I'm making a REST service using Restler, however I've found that when I pass it the `ñ` character, the whole parameter becomes null.

Is this because of REST or because some weird encoding that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

While I do not know if this is the case in your situation, generally HTTP is not a safe-transport for extended character sets like Unicode.  I've found base64 to be the best way to transport data between the REST client and server.